# How to footnotes using itext?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, footer

I want a footer that contains a description for a reference mark (footnote), It is a small number next to a word, and it is explained in the footer. I already have the code to create the footer, but I cannot find a way to put the numbers of the reference mark, neither in the text itself neither in the footer.

```
 Font fontTimes = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, 
 Font.NORMAL);
 PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
 table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.TOP);
 table.addCell("*mark1* explanation");

 table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(document.leftMargin()), 
 table.getTotalHeight() + document.bottom(document.bottomMargin()), 
 writer.getDirectContent());
```

I have created a list with sub lists, these lists basically have Paragraphs as ItemLists. These items own some laws informations, that should be explained inside the footer. I'm creating those lists this way:

```
List romanList= new RomanList();
romanList.add(new ListItem(new Paragraph("item1:", bondFont)));

ArrayList<String> phrases = new ArrayList<>();
phrases.add("Fundamented in Federal law number 19.003/1998*mark1*");
List subList1 = createSubList(phrases, font, true, false);
```

---

```
private List createSubList(ArrayList<String> items, Font font, boolean 
   ehNumber, boolean ehLetter) {

    List subList = new List(ehNumber, ehLetter);
    for (String description : items) {
       Paragraph para = new Paragraph(description, font);
       subList.add(new ListItem(para));
    }
    return subList;
 }
```

That's basically all I have at the moment, after creating the lists, I add them to the document. You can see that, inside the sub list, I've added a Paragraph that contains a law, it has to own a reference mark (footnote), and I want to be able to reference it to the footer to put a description.

Comment: I understand you correctly that you need (at most) one footnote per page?

Comment: I need one or more footnote per page, and some pages, I don't want it. I'm thing that's not possible... at least not easily

Comment: @mkl If you are a jaspersoft god, can we talk in a chat?

Comment: I'm not a *god*. I'm quite knowledgeable as far as iText is concerned but in respect to JasperReports my knowledge is mediocre.

Comment: Well, I'm using jaspersoft now, but if you have any knowledge about creating footnotes I would like to know. I was really locked with that in my sytem that's why I'm using jasper now (even thought I don't recommend it).

Comment: Well, I don't have a generic solution with iText at my hand, in particular not one that dynamically allows a footnote area grow from the bottom while the main text is written starting at the top. A solution reserving a fixed footer area on all pages and writing the foot notes there would be feasible, though.